# npm install with Github Automatic authentication in CI

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, github-actions, npm-install

I would like to use [Github's Automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) with `npm install` in my CI (Continuous Integration) setup. As far as I understand, the `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` is automatically populated by GitHub. However, when I run the CI process, I encounter an error message saying:

> Permission_denied: read_package

I have included my CI configuration below. If you have any suggestions or ideas, they would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18

      - name: Authenticate with GitHub token
        run: echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
```

Comment: You need to specify the `permissions` according to your use case i.e. read or write. See this [example](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-nodejs-packages#example-workflow).

Comment: Also, see [Authenticating to GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages).

Comment: Azeem, according to the last link you provided the only option that I have is PAT because my repository uses other repository's packages. For example: "base-repo" has "icon" package that is hold in other repository "my-icons". Did I understood right? Documentation seems confusing for me. 

Big thanks for your first response.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For using other repo's packages which are not public, you need to use a PAT with correct permissions. It was not clear from your question that you're trying to install packages from other repo(s). You might want to include that in your question as well.

Comment: Azeem, I am sorry for not explaining in details. Thanks for help buddy.